# Convincing postfix and Google Apps to play nice on the same domain?

Tags: email, postfix, g-suite

OK - so I've never installed or worked with postfix before, so forgive me if this is fairly basic.

I have example.com all set up and working nicely with Google apps. Email comes and goes with no problem. I needed to provide a way for apps to email me, though, so I installed postfix.

It now emails out to all domains OTHER than example.com just fine, but if it tries to email an @example.com address and that address exists, it keeps the email local rather than pushing it out to the web and over to the gmail servers.

Any hints on how to fix this?

Comment: post your postfix main.cf here, it will be much easier to tell you then what adjustments need to be done than to blindly figure out where you misconfigured it.

Comment: OK - main.cf posted at http://pastebin.com/X6ELTJWM

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

It was the mydestination line in the config file.

Thanks for the pointer, Hrvoje!